# Proof about combinations but with a combinatorial argument

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Let $\Omega_n={1,2,....,n}$ and for $0 \leq k \leq n$ let $\Omega^{\{k\}}$ be the collection of k element subsets of $\Omega_n$

Define the number $S^{n}_{k}$ as cardinality of $\Omega^{\{k\}}_n$

Prove that $S^{n}_{k}={n \choose k}$ by the method of counting in two different wats. Let X= $\Omega^{\{k\}}_n$ and $Y=\{(n_1, n_2, . . . , n_k)|n_i \in \Omega_{n} \text{ and are distinct}\}$. Use the relation R which is the set of all pairs $(A,(n_1, . . . , n_k))$ such that $\{n_1, n_2, . . . , n_k\} = A$.

Approach: I know that I have to use a combinatorial argument, but I just can't understand the wording of this problem. I am completely blocked from this part:
Let X=$\Omega^{\{k\}}_n$ and $Y=\{(n_1, n_2, . . . , n_k)|n_i \in \Omega_{n} \text{ and are distinct}\}$. Use the relation R which is the set of all pairs $(A,(n_1, . . . , n_k))$ such that $\{n_1, n_2, . . . , n_k\} = A$.

what is X, what is Y what is R how do they relate to the problem?

Comment: Please don't deliberately [duplicate questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1807865); this is an abuse of the site.

Comment: it's not a duplicate. It's a different question with the same title

Comment: I went over it twice and I can't spot a single difference in the problem statement; as far as I can tell, you merely added your approach. If you insist that there's a difference, please point it out.

Comment: It's saying create $X$ and $Y$ using the definitions given and then use their properties to solve.  $Y$ appears to be the elements of $\omega_n$ which are distinct. So it would appear $\omega_n$ can generate duplicate values; you are only to assemble the distinct ones into $Y$.

Comment: The problem is very similar. In my last post, I had to use induction. In this post, I have to use a combinatorial argument. Sorry for the inconvenience, but math stack exchange is my only source of help to get my homework done.

Comment: So Y is the complement of X?. I understand now what X is but Y is still bothering me. Y={(n1,n2,...,nk)|ni∈Ωn. What is the ni?

Comment: I've flagged this for the moderators. Your behaviour is very destructive. You needlessly duplicated a question and insist on keeping it after I pointed this out. Contrary to what you write, the other question does not specify that you want a solution using induction. It has "combinatorics" both in the title and as a tag. Everyone who encounters that question without knowing that you duplicated it here will likely waste effort duplicating the search for a combinatorial argument. You could have simply added the part that says you're looking for a combinatorial argument.

Comment: I've deleted the older question since this one now has an answer, and it's better formatted. But don't re-post your questions, edit the original instead.

Answer (score 0):

The idea: first to count the number of tuples $(n_1,\dots,n_k)$ where the $n_i$ are distinct elements of $\Omega_n$. The result of that counting is the cardinality of set $Y$ and it equals $$n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)$$

Do you see why?

A tuple $(n_1,n_2\dots,n_k)\in Y$ induces a subset $\{n_1,n_2\dots,n_k\}$ of $\Omega_n$ that has cardinality $k$. However, e.g. tuple $(n_2,n_1\dots,n_k)\in Y$ where $n_1,n_2$ are switched gives the same subset. This indicates overcounting that must be repaired. This by dividing the cardinality of $Y$ by the number of tuples $\tau\in Y$ that satisfy $\tau R(n_1,\cdots,n_k)$.

A tuple $\tau$ that satisfies can be written $(n_{\sigma(1)},\dots,n_{\sigma(k)})$ as where $\sigma$ is a permutation on $\{1,\dots,k\}$.

There are $k!$ permutions so the end result is:$$n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)/k!=\binom{n}{k}$$

Comment: Let me see if I understand the first idea. You wanna count different tuples. Does $n_i$ imply difference. How are they different. If they are different, they have to differ at least by one element or they have to differ by the ordering.

Comment: If e.g. $n=3$ and $k=2$ then I find the $3\times2=6$ tuples $(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,3),(3,1),(3,2)$. The $n_i$ are demanded to be distinct, so not the tuples $(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)$. This leads to the sets $\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\dots$ but every set is counted $2!=2$ times (note that $\{1,2\}=\{2,1\}$). So to repair you must divide by $2!$. Final result: $3=\binom32$ subsets of $\{1,2,3\}$ that have cardinality $2$.

Comment: To find the number of tuples: for $n_1$ there are $n$ choices; for $n_2$ there are $n-1$ choices left then, et cetera.